# How do I replace any number X in ",Xf" to floating point - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` where I want to set out `f` for every number. The problem is some numbers are integers, and then it will collide.

Let's say we have the matrix `X_point` and I want to convert it into a C float array, without brackets.

```
   px = strrep(mat2str(X_point), ']', 'f');
   px = strrep(px, '[', '');
   px = strrep(px, ' ', 'f,');
   px = strrep(px, ';', 'f,');
   px = strrep(px, ',0f', ',0.0f');
   px = strrep(px, ',0,', ',0.0f,');
```

The issue here is that if I got an integer, non `0` number, then the result will look like this. You see the problem here?

```
px = 45.8719f,57.6531f,59.3361f,57.2791f,47.9289f,37.6438f,37.8308f,45.8719f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,67.5643f,79.5325f,83.8336f,83.6466f,78.5975f,69.8083f,61.5802f,55.0351f,53.913f,55.7831f,56.9051f
,67.5643f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,12.7723f,18.5694f,20.4395f,22.1225f,21.1875f,19.6914f,16.3254f
,11.4633f,8.8453f,8.8453f,2.3001f,0.6171f,-0.3179f,-3.1024f,-4f,-4.2244f,-4.2244f,-4.2244f,1.8345f,4.7518f,7.2202f,12.7723
f,72.9705f,74.5414f,80.8247f,94.7377f,96.533f,100.5722f,101.8177f,99.7232f,94.7489f,90.2983f,84.015f,78.2553f,75.6372f,72.
9705f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,8.6152f,34.7957f,32.9631f,0.2375f,8.6152f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f
,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f
```

This is the problem `,-4f,`

My question is simple. How can I say that any number in `,Xf` should be a floating point number?

If there is a way to convert every integer number in matrix `X_point`, then this would be much easier.

Comment: This question is not about the C language. You can initialize an array of `float` in C without the `f` suffix.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, but then it will be from `double` to `float` casting.

Comment: You might get a warning, but it is still allowed. I'm not sure why you want `float` instead of `double` in the first place.

Comment: @chqrlie Because it's for embedded software. Float is faster =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue.

To convert a MATLAB matrix `X_point` into C-array `px` with float expresion

```
   px = sprintf('%0.4ff,', X_point);
   px(end) = ''; % Remove the last ','
```